# Closing Low Quality Posts: More Options

Tags: feature-request, reviews

A lot of the time, low quality answers are either irrelevant or are better stated as a comment on the question. There is no option to provide feedback on either of these, since they are not comments on another answer, spam, link only, or a different question. I propose adding two more options:

This is a comment, not an answer*
and
This has nothing to do with the question asked*.
*or something similar

Comment: Is this about the canned comments in the review queues, for answers? Keep in mind that you can always add a custom comment first, then recommend an action without adding any further comment.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: `Is this about the canned comments in the review queues, for answers? ` Yes it is. When a dozen answers can be summarised by "Irrelevant" or "This would be better off as a comment", it gets annoying to have to repeat the same statement over and over. Especially with the minimum number of characters issue

Comment: You can always just write a completely new, normal comment, thereby giving the OP useful feedback for his specific case and then choose "no comment needed" when clicking on the "Recommend Deletion" button. It takes a bit more time but is far more useful and always applicable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I agree that the choices for standard comments to leave on posts in the review queues are... shall I say not always the most helpful, especially for someone who doesn't already know how Stack Exchange works,

In the case of the two specific ones you propose:

> This is a comment, not an answer

This case seems to be covered by the existing "This does not provide an answer to the question."

> This has nothing to do with the question asked

This case seems to be covered by the existing "This does not provide an answer to the question."

Also, this is something that is outside of the purview of each individual site, being network-wide functionality.

Comment: Fair enough....